# How to gzip javascript and css files to improve the page speed

Tags: javascript, css, gzip

I have a website and now i want to improve the page speed of the site so i want to gzip the javascript,css files , can any one suggest me and explain how to this ...

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666120/how-to-gzip-my-js-and-css-files You may want to change your webserver configuration.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593806/compress-javascript-with-gzip/12593831#12593831

Answer (score 2):

When you're using the apache webserver you can add the following bit of configuration to the server config or an .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
     <LocationMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
         SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
     </LocationMatch>
</IfModule>
```